# Proving that the composition of derivations on an algebra is not a derivation

Tags: real-analysis

This is problem 2.4 in An Introduction to Manifolds in Loring W. Tu

Repeating the definition in case it is not standard, a derivation is a linear map $D: C^\infty_p \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which respects the Leibniz rule:

$$D(fg) = (Df)g(p) + f(p)Dg$$

The problem is to show that given derivations $D_1$ and $D_2$, $D_1 \circ D_2$ is not necessarily a derivation.

Here is what I came up with:
Obviously, the composition of linear maps is linear, so that criteria is easily met. So let's check the Leibniz rule.

$$(D_1 \circ D_2)(fg) = D_1(D_2fg(p)) + D_1(f(p)D_2g)$$
$$ = ((D_1 \circ D_2) f)g(p) + f(p)(D_1 \circ D_2) g + (D_2f)(p)D_1g(p) + D_1f(p)D_2g$$

Now, I'm pretty sure what I'm supposed to conclude at this point is that the last two terms are why the Leibniz rule does not work.

However, notice the terms $D_1g(p)$ and $D_2f(p)$. Those are derivations of the functions $f$ and $g$ after those functions have been evaluated at $p$. That seems wrong since $g(p) \in \mathbb{R}$. So at best, I would expect $g(p)$ to be a constant function. So those terms would vanish.

What mistake am I making?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to find an example to illustrate that. Suppose that $M=\mathbb{R}$
and $Df(x)=f'(x)$. $D(D(f))=f"(x)$, $D(fg)=f'g+fg'$ ($D$ is a derivation), $D(D(fg))=D(f'g)+D(fg')=f"g+f'g'+f'g'+fg"=fD(D(g))+D(D(f))g=fg"+gf"$ if an only if $f'g'=0$, this is not always true.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is late but a heads up for those reading this later, the question from Tu you are referring to is asking about derivations of an algebra which is different from a derivations of a point $p \in \mathbb{R}^n$. You have written a the definition of a derivation at a point $p$: a linear map $D: C_p^\infty \to \mathbb{R}$ that satisfies a the Leibniz rule. A derivation of an algebra $A$ over a field $K$ is a linear map $D: A \to A$ that satisfies the Liebniz rule.